# Github page not showing my index.html file

Tags: github, web-hosting, github-pages

I am new to github pages so I made the following repo with a simple index.html
https://github.com/jigneshjain25/jignesh.github.com/blob/gh-pages/index.html

but http://jignesh.github.com/ shows "Hello World" only. Why its not using my index.html file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not publishing to the master branch, but the gh-pages branch, yet you are trying to deploy a user page. Also it needs to be http://jigneshjain25.github.com because that's your username.

https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages

The account that controls that Hello World has been set-up properly, here:

https://github.com/jignesh/jignesh.github.com/blob/master/index.html

Comment: OMG I was accessing somebody else's github page and thought it was mine and that "Hello World" is what comes default, lol.

Comment: Note that now you should use *username*.github.io not *username*.github.com